# How to check triple exists or not?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Firstly, I was intended to express query like `COUNT(?sub) AS ?sub_exists` and check whether `?sub_exists` is 0 or not with the count number. However, this query takes too much time so that sometimes it takes more than timeout. So I secondly tried to change the function like below. But it also takes all the time counting `?sub` and even worse, no values are assigned to `?sub_exists`.

Is there an alternative way to express the query to **just check** a triple `?sub wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?s` exists or not and get the flag of it correspondly without two much time consumption ?

```
SELECT ?s ?sub_exists
WHERE {
  VALUES ?s {wd:Q5}
  ?sub wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?s
  BIND(IF(COUNT(?sub) > 0,1,0) AS ?sub_exists)
}
GROUP BY ?s ?sub_exists
```

Answer (score 4):

SPARQL provides a good alternative ! ASK will return true or false if pattern exists or not, respectively.

Here is a working example :

```
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

ASK  {
  ?sub wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?s
}
```

Comment: Spoiler, the answer is true.